# dropdown filtering in multiple rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple rows and each contains a dropdown with Labels.
Labels = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
If we select "A" as a Label in first row, "B" in second row, "C" in third row
We should only show the selected Label and the available Labels in the dropdown.
Ex: In first row dropdown-show "A","D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"
This should be for all. I am using javascript and angular js. 
Could some one please give a efficient way to resolve this. 
I have an idea of having selected Labels flag and showLabels flag but we need to loop it for every row and in real time application i can have more than 100 rows and dont want to loop 100 times for every row. Please help.

---

| A        ^ |  | Delete Button |

---

---

| B        ^ |  | Delete Button |

### --------------  -----------------

### | Add Line|  |

In First dropdown values should be “A, C,D,E,F,G,H”
In Second dropdown values should be “B, C,D,E,F,G,H”

When we add a row we get a new row and the drop down should contain “C,D,E,F,G,H"

Comment: I'm confused, as I understand: you have multiple stacked, clickable, horizontal rows(like a menu) and when you click one you want it to no longer display? Could you include a picture perhaps? Like just make something in paint if you're not skilled. Or show an example that is working on another site?

Comment: you could simply generate the list when the dropdown occurs

Comment: Have you tried writing a filter? Then you could just filter your ng-repeat and if it is already selected throw it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it easily using the [lodash](http://lodash.com/) library to manipulate arrays and collections.

**EDIT-1:** I added an alternative and modified the plunker accordingly.

**EDIT-2:** I added an other alternative using a custom filter

**DEMO:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Sf3el0FyUptWq28XqZnI?p=preview

Let's say that you have a certain number of rows (list) each having a dropdown (select). The dropdown must have all the values that were not selected yet (remaining).

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in list">
      {{item.id}}-{{item.value}}
      <select ng-model="item.value" ng-options="letter for letter in remaining"></select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Whenever a item of the list change the dropdown value, the remaining values are updated.

**js**

```
$scope.$watch('list', function(newval) {
    $scope.remaining = _.difference($scope.letters, _.map(newval, 'value'));
}, true);
```

The possible list of values:

```
$scope.letters = [
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'
]
```

The list of items:

```
$scope.list = [
    {id:1,value:''},
    {id:2,value:''},
    {id:3,value:''},
    {id:4,value:''},
    {id:5,value:''},
    {id:6,value:''},
    {id:7,value:''},
    {id:8,value:''}
];
```

**lodash**

We use lodash to easily `_.map` the `value` property of all the items in the list to an array. And we want the `_.difference` between the selected and the possible values.

**alternative tracking previous values**

If your list of possible values is represented as a string (`$scope.letters='ABCDEFGHIJ';`), then you can keep track of the remaining values as a string too (`$scope.remaining='BDEGHJ';`). Then, instead of `$watch`ing every changes, you can use the `ng-change` directive on the dropdowns and add or remove the values with a simple `string.replace`. You need to keep track of the previously selected values in order to put them back in the list when they are switched.

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in list2">
        {{item.id}}-{{item.value}}
        <select ng-model="item.value" ng-change="select(item)" ng-options="letter for letter in remaining2"></select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**js**

```
var last = [];
$scope.select = function(item) {
    $scope.remaining2 = $scope.remaining2.replace(item.value,last[item.id]||'');
    last[item.id] = item.value;
}
```

Here I use the `item.id` to keep track of the previous value of each items, but you could think of another approach.

**alternative using a filter**

*This has not been tested, but it should work.*

There are a lot of other ways to achieve this, for example, using a custom $filter on the list of all possible values (the filter would need access to the currently selected values). It could be a simple wrapper of one of my solutions.

**html**

```
<select ng-model="item.value" ng-options="letter for letter in letters | notselected:list:'value'"></select>
```

This will take as input the `$scope.letters` and remove the ones used in `$scope.list`. We must tell the filter which property correspond to the selected values in the collection.

**js**

```
app.filter('notselected', function() {
    return function(input, list, prop) {
        return _.difference(input, _.map(list, prop));
    }
});
```

This might be the most elegant solution in my opinion. Lodash is an amazing library and works like a charm with Angular!