# hide a specific ng-option if it's id already exists in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a drop down that adds items on a page that are binded to a $scope. I basically want to make sure I don't add doubles to the array so my idea is to ng-hide the option if it already exists in the array. I don't know if it's possible to do something like this because the ng-options is inside the select so I dont know if i can append an ng-hide to them in the first place.

Regardless, if it is possible, I would like to hide the option if it's id already exists in a scope.

I was thinking you would just loop through each and check, here is my attempt

```
$scope.checkifExist = function () {
    var ifExist = false;
    angular.forEach($scope.promptsPlease, function (data) {

        if (data.id == $scope.promptsPlease.id){

            ifExist = true;
        }

    });
    return ifExist;

    };
```

and so the select in the controller looks like

```
  <select ng-model="fadingSelected" ng-options="type.name for type in fadingTypes track by type.id" ng-hide="checkIfExist()">
            </select>
```

I don't know if this is even possible, and I think I might just be approaching this all wrong. The idea is just so I cannot add the same one twice to the array that's binded to the scope. It doesn't necessarily have to ng-hide, it would just be nice. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks for reading.

Comment: Use a filter instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644402/angular-use-filter-on-ng-options-to-change-the-value-displayed

Answer (score 1):

This previous answer might apply to your problem (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19329910/1036025).

Here is the included demo (plunker): http://plnkr.co/edit/Sf3el0FyUptWq28XqZnI?p=preview

It illustrates 3 ways of achieving this. One is using the library `lodash` to manipulate your data and create a filtered list of the available choices instead of using `angular.each`.

I would recommend you to have a look at the 3rd explained option in the description (alternative using a filter).

Comment: this is a great example, I am struggling though because it is a single drop down and its tyring to track a sub array thats nested 3 nested ng repeats down.

Comment: You should put all the concerned code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible only when ng-repeat option tag

```
<select ng-model="fadingSelected">
    <option ng-if="checkIfExist()" ng-bind="type.name" ng-value="type.id" ng-repeat="type in fadingTypes track by type.id"></option>
</select>
```